Sort range in Google Sheets
I use Google Sheets. I have a column in random order:

How can I sort it like this:

and not:


I modified my answer to use *1 as it is shorter than the TEXT function (number padding) based approach and does not need to be adjusted if the length of numbers changes. Better approach.

TL;DR
=SORT(A:A, IF(A:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+")*1),1)

Problem
Sheets sorts text the same way a dictionary would based on each character starting from the left:
Ascending: {"txt-1", "txt-11", "txt-2", "txt-225", "txt-27"}

Solution

Extract the numbers into an array to use as a sort column. Simply extracting the numbers is not enough as they will be number strings and still sort like dictionary text:
Ascending: {"1", "11", "2", "225", "27"}


To get them to sort like numbers you need to either coerce them to numbers using a math calculation or pad the shorter number strings with additional 0 digits:
Text:    {"001", "002", "011", "027", "225"}
Numbers: {1, 2, 11, 27, 225}

Coerce number strings to numbers   (ascending followed by desc.)
=SORT(A:A, IF(A:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+")*1),1)
=SORT(A:A, IF(A:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+")*1),) 

Pad the shorter numbers with zeros   (ascending followed by desc.)
=SORT(A:A, IF(A:A="",,TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+"),"00")),1)
=SORT(A:A, IF(A:A="",,TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+"),"00")),)

IF  REGEXEXTRACT  SORT  TEXT


